# Working with Swift completion handlers for chained functions

Tags: swift, chaining, completionhandler

I am chaining some functions together and I can't figure out how to call a completion handler with a return value once all the functions are done running.

```
class AirQualityProvider {
    var aBlock: ((Int?) -> Void)?

    func getAirQuality(completion: @escaping (Int?) -> Void) {
        aBlock = completion
        callAPI()
    }

    private func callAPI() {
        let data = Data()
        parseDataForAQI(data: data)
    }

    private func parseDataForAQI(data: Data) {

        for d in data {
            dosomeMath(d)
        }
    }


    private func dosomeMath(data: Int) {

        // HERE IS WHERE I WANT IT TO SUM UP ALL THE NUMBERS
        THEN ONLY RETURN ONE VALUE using a completion handler.
        Currently, it returns the average as it is being generated.
    }
```

Almost got it working with help to Alexander. The code Alexander supplied works perfectly, it is amazing. The issue is, when I run taskrunner inside alamofire it returns empty. Outside alamofire it works as usual. I need to run this inside alamofire.

```
func A(json : JSON){
    for (key,subJson) in json{
        if subJson["free"].doubleValue > 0.0 {
            func B(asset: subJson["asset"].stringValue, json: subJson)
        }
    }

    print(taskRunner.getResults())
}


func B(asset : String, json : JSON){

        //OUTSIDE ALAMOFIRE WORKS
            self.taskRunner.execute{
            return 100
        }

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in

       //INSIDE ALAMOFIRE DOESN'T WORK. Returns []
            self.taskRunner.execute{
            return 100
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for a `DispatchGroup`

Comment: Thanks for your input. How would a DispatchGroup function work for this exactly? Thanks!

Comment: `DispatchGroup`s are to wait till all asynchronously made calls are finished and then maybe continue executing or call a notify function.

Could you return from every doSomeMath some values and put all the mathResults somehow together into a number and call the closure like `aBlock(numberPutInto)` in `parseDataForAQI(data:)`?

Comment: @Red Can you please put your thoughts into code? ... I don't see how a dispatch group can fix this issue considering function "dosomemath" is being called in a loop.

Comment: @Alexander Please check above comment on my issues with using dispatchgroup

Comment: You can call the callback with `aBlock(resultInteger)` as usual. Maybe `aBlock!(resultInteger), cause `aBlock` optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a dispatch queue to synchronize the aggregation of results (by synchronizing `Array.append(_:)` calls, and the subsequent reading of the array). Here's a simple example:

```
import Dispatch
import Foundation

class ParallelTaskRunner<Result> {
    private var results = [Result]()
    private let group = DispatchGroup()
    private let resultAggregatorQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Result Aggregator")

    func execute(_ closure: (@escaping (Result) -> Void) -> Void) {
        group.enter() // Register that a new task is in-flight
        closure { result in
            self.resultAggregatorQueue.sync { // Synchronize access to the array
                self.results.append(result) // Record the result
            }
            self.group.leave() // This task is done
        }
    }

    func getResults() -> [Result] {
        group.wait() // Make sure all in-flight tasks are done
        return resultAggregatorQueue.sync { return results }
    }
}




let taskQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Task Queue", attributes: .concurrent)
let taskRunner = ParallelTaskRunner<Int>()
for i in 0...100 {
    taskRunner.execute { completionHandler in 
        taskQueue.async { // Simulated async computation
            let randomTime = 3.0
            print("Sleeping for \(randomTime)")
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: randomTime) // Simulates intesnive computation
            let result = i // Simulate a result
            completionHandler(result)
        }
    }
}
print(taskRunner.getResults()) // Oh look, all the results are here! :D
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, seems that this could work. Just confused on exactly how to apply this to my code considering my class is extremely long.

Comment: @tenkdarko Why does it matter if your class is long? (although that's a good indication that you should simplify it by breaking it down into smaller, simpler pieces)

Comment: Hm, can you show me how i can apply this solution to my current problem. The code is seems nice just not seeing the connection.

Comment: @tenkdarko I can't get particularly specific, because your example is quite vauge. But the point here is that you can iterate over all your cases, make the API call for them using the `execute` method in my  `ParallelTaskRunner`, and then you can collect all the results using `getResults()`, then you can sum those (or combine them however you wish), and return the single result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. Your code is amazing. Please take a look at my edit to see the issue i'm having with your code. Your code works perfectly just doesn't run in alamofire. It returns an empty array.

Comment: @tenkdarko My example uses `taskQueue.async` to provide async parallelism. Alamofire provides that on its own. You would need to remove that part of the code. You need to ensure the `group.enter()` is called for every work item, and that `group.exit()` is called in the Alamofire completion handler, after the result has been added to the result array. That way, the group is exited not when the work item is registered, but when it actually completes its result have been made available.

Comment: @tenkdarko I've updated my answer, although it's probably better to investigate using the `queue` parameter of the alamofire calls, using the prev version of my answer

Comment: Same issue both with your new and previous code. The values are actually getting inserted I checked by calling get-results continuously (with both old and new). For some reason putting it in the alamofire messes up it automatically calling getResult once everything is done...

Comment: Well the problem is that the call to Alamofire is asynchronous. The thread of execution resumes immediately once that async call is done, but that actual async work doesn't happen until later. As a result, the dispatch group is left too early, and `getResults()` doesn't end up properly waiting for all async work to complete

Comment: Got it working using alamofire... issue it it stops other processes I have from running until it is complete.

Comment: @tenkdarko Well currently, `getResults()` block the current thread to await the completion of all results. You'll want to asynchronously call that

Comment: Thank you for your kind help!